# Tomcat can't find index when not on top level of webapp dir

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, angular, angular-cli

Our issue is we simply don't know how to tell Tomcat our index.html is not at the top level of the webapp folder anymore, it's one folder deeper.

Our app on the server is a Spring, Maven, Hibernate project deployed on Tomcat9. On the front we are using Angular2 with Angular-CLI magic.

The back-end and front-end are two separate projects so front-end dudes don't need to deal with Java and vice-versa. Then we simply use some build magic to combine the deploy-able Angular2 artifacts into the webapp folder so Maven can pack it in the WAR.

We ended up in this scenario because of Angular-CLI and how it wants to lay out the project, like below. The index.html refers to the node_modules directly one directory up either way and angular-cli does not like us changing this.

(1) un-built angular-cli project

```
|-- web-project
   |-- src
      |-- index.html
   |-- node_modules
   |-- package.json
   |-- angular-cli.json
```

(2) Structure when built into Maven project. The dist folder is generated by angular-cli for the deploy-able artifacts.

```
|-- webapp
   |-- dist
      |-- index.html
   |-- node_modules
   |-- WEB-INF
      |-- web.xml
      |-- (bunch of spring configs)
```

Prior to Angular-CLI we just used the layout described in the main Angular2 websites tutorial from the link below. This tutorial has changed a lot since I checked last.

[Angular2 Main Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

The layout of the original way worked totally fine with Tomcat because the "index.html" file was at the top level with a structure like below. However Angular-CLI cleared a bunch of tasks needed for the build, so the CLI is the way to go.

```
|-- webapp
   |-- index.html
   |-- node_modules
   |-- WEB-INF
```

Earlier we had a fork in the road where we could either (1) tell tomcat about this, or (2) change the Angular-CLI setup. Since the CLI is so new and the structure kinda makes sense, I figured Tomcat would handle this conundrum better and more peeps could help me.

There are two files which seem like the place to be to nail this.

(1) resource-mapping.xml (a spring config)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for the index.html file -->
    <!-- Huh? How does this work? -->
    <resources mapping="/*" location="/" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by serving static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <resources mapping="/node_modules/**" location="/node_modules/" />

    <resources mapping="/themes/**" location="/themes/" />

    <!-- Opens up the dist folder -->
    <resources mapping="/dist/**" location="/dist/" />

</beans:beans>
```

(2) MainController.java

```java
package com.mydomain.myapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page. 
 * @author Some friends and I
 */
@Controller
public class MainController {

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view statically by forwarding to index.html
     * 
     * @return "/index.html".
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "/index.html";
    }

}
```

In the Spring config above, the first mapping somehow works in conjunction with the MainController java file to serve the index.html. Most of our problem stems from not knowing how or why this actually works and we've never had the index.html anywhere but the top level before.

So far we have tried some of the more obvious approaches by putting dist in front of the paths like so:`return "/dist/index.html"`, but to no avail.

We tried quite a few combinations but we always get basically the same error with a few words changed around.

```
type Exception report

message Could not resolve view with name '/dist/index.html' in servlet with name 'appServlet'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/dist/index.html' in servlet with name 'appServlet'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1211)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9 logs.
```

So does anyone see what I am missing here? Anyone else ever have the index.html somewhere else other than the top level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the web.xml file and add a  tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>dist/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  ....rest of tags...
</web-app>
```

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. I even thought about this but for some reason I thought Spring would handle this instead. Seems like this makes our MainController.java kind of useless.